# Process file from <select> field in activeadmin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a select that goes like this on one of my activeadmin forms:

```
f.input :sdfile, :as => :select, :collection => Dir.glob("incoming/*")
```

The user is supposed to upload the file to a "incoming" dir beforehand.

I now want to process this file, moving it to the proper folder, but CarrierWave refuses to "upload" from a pathname.

Any easy way to process the file, moving it to the respective folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Image.new :data=>File.new("/path/to/image.jpg","r")
```

or

```
Image.new :data=>File.open('/path/to/image.jpg', 'rb')
```

Comment: How do i go about that?
I can't feed the :select with an Image instance. I'm supposing i'll have to write a custom controller for the form? Is it possible at all?